# How to enlarge Custom Question Answering Editor Window in Language Studio

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker, nlp-question-answering, language-studio

The existing QnA maker editor will be always better than the current custom question answering in the azure language studio. We have added 600+ QnA question pairs in custom question answering but the editor is very small and we can able to see only one question pair at a time, remeaning we need to scroll down.

This will be a hectic problem for us to manage all the content in the custom question answering and is there any way to enlarge/maximize this editor in full size window?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the UI was built in such manner. There is no specific procedure to enlarge the screen size of the editor.

Comment: @TadepalliSairam how you can satisfy your customers with this particular UI? Also, this will really impact content management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new editor window is pretty good and was updated a couple of days back.

[image]